# How R performs the operations like Inf + Inf, Inf * Inf, Inf - Inf and Inf / Inf?

Tags: r

In R When we do some operation like `Inf + Inf`, `Inf * Inf` gives `Inf` back, whereas similar operation  `Inf - Inf` and `Inf / Inf`gives results as `NaN`, how R actually handles these type of concepts

Answer (score 2):

`Inf` is a reserved word in R, so it is handled at interpreter level. That is, similar to `FALSE & TRUE` $\rightarrow$ `FALSE` and `FALSE | TRUE` $\rightarrow$ `TRUE`, when interpreter is faced with `Inf ? Inf`, it decides what to do based on the operation `?`. You can think of a set of if-then rules under the hood that resolve the expression to `Inf` for `+` and `*`, and to `NaN` for `-` and `/`, no complicated inference is involved.